# How do I add rows under existing rows in Excel and then add columns to the right?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an existing product spreadsheet with hundreds of rows of data in it. Some of the products have variant versions, and so they have two EXTRA rows beneath them, one for Variant 1 and one for Variant 2. I need to create those extra rows for EVERY product.

I basically have a 3 row x 14 column selection I need to duplicate for every product. If it were just new columns or just new rows, that would be easy, but because it's columns AND rows, I'm stuck.

**Is there a way to rapidly insert my selection for every variant?** (I do have some cells in each product row that change, but I assume I'll have to handle those 2-3 cells per row manually).

A full row has 37 columns with content in them. The only ones that change per product are the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 6th, and 7th, with the variants having blank columns 3-9 and different info in the 10th, 12th, 15th-22nd columns (compared to the existing product row). Of those, only the 10th and 18th columns differ between variants.

Example of a normal product row followed by 2 variant rows:
[Rows in Excel: Headers, Product Row, 2 Variant Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWg0B.jpg)

Example of a normal product row without any variants (what I need to edit):
[Row in Excel: Product Row before Variants are added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yinxh.png)

Comment: please add some sample data with desired output, it'll make more easier to understand your situation.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & upload some sample data along with expected results,, help us to understand the issue to fix it.

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?

Comment: Ok, I've added examples -- I hope these are what folks are asking for! The second example is what I have hundreds of, unedited; the top example is what I'm hoping to get as an output.

Comment: if I understand it right.. You mean the original "1 row with 37 columns" will become "3 rows and 14 columns" right ?